# Finding minimal polynomial with given operator

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, characteristic-functions, minimal-polynomials

Given the operator $T:\mathbb C_{\le n}[x]→\mathbb C_{\le n}[x]$ such that $T(p) = p' + p$  find the minimal polynomial.

What I tried:

I found the representing matrix $$A = \begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 2 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & 0 & \ddots & \ddots & 0\\
0 & \cdots & 0 & 1 & n\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}$$
and then I found the characteristic polynomial:
$f_T(x) = (x-1)^{n+1}$.

Now I know that the minimal polynomial is $m_T \in \{(x-1),(x-1)^2,\space...\space,\space(x-1)^{n+1}\}$

My guess is that $m_T = (x-1)^{n+1}$ but I don't know how to find which one it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's denote by $S$ the derivative operator $S(p) = p'$. You noted that the minimal polynomial of $T$ has the form $(x-1)^k$ for $1 \leq k \leq n + 1$ so let $m(x) = (x-1)^k$. For $m$ to be the minimal polynomial of $T$, we must have

$$ m(T) = (T - I)^k = S^k = 0. $$

However, if $k \leq n$ then 
$$ S^k(x^k) = k! \neq 0$$

so we must have $k = n + 1$. And indeed, $S^{n+1}$ acts on polynomials by taking the derivative $n + 1$ times and since all the polynomials $S$ acts on are of degree $ \leq n$ we get $S^{n+1} = 0$.